# Deploy Java app to Heroku using Git

Tags: java, heroku

My project written using the Spark framework has this build config.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.avaje</groupId>
                <artifactId>ebean-maven-enhancement-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>main</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <classSource>target/classes</classSource>
                    <packages>somepath.domain.**</packages>
                    <transformArgs>debug=1</transformArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Its main class resides in `somepath.Bootstrap`.

The `Procfile` sits next to the `pom`.

[image: Procfile]

What should the contents of the `Procfile` be?

(I am deploying via git.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java#the-procfile) contains command, that will be executed after deploying your appliaction (`git push heroku master` for you example i guess).
I do not very familiar with spark, but i guess it can be something like this:

```
web: mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="somepath.Bootstrap"
```

Comment: No, `mvn` won't be available at runtime (it's a build tool, and not intended for running your app in production). Better to use a `java` command to run a Java class

Answer (score 1):

A [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) is a mechanism for declaring what commands are run by your application’s dynos on the Heroku platform.

Here is an example for a Java app:

```
web: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main
```

This is taken from a [Heroku Java sample app](https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started) that uses Spark.

Be aware that build tools, such as Maven, will not be available at runtime.